# Combine * ngIf property in Angular into an Input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ng-if, angular11

I have a project in Angular 11 and Angular material in which I am trying to combine the `*ngIf` property with the readOnly property to avoid putting two Inputs.

This is my `component.html`:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex!=i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'none'">
              <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="true">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex==i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'legacy'">
              <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

Right now I have two `mat-form-field` each with an Imput, one `[readonly]="true"` depending on the `*ngIf = "editIndex! = I"` property. How could I combine both to put only one mat-form-field with one Input?

This is what I want to try but I don't know how to do it or if it can be done:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
      <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'none'">
          <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" *ngIf="editIndex!=i; [readonly]="true"">
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Most properties and attributes could be set conditionally in Angular. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#property-and-attribute-comparison) for more info. So instead of two separate `<input>`s you could try `<input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">`. In this case the `*ngIf` directive isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set conditional `readonly` and `appearance` also.

```
 <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
     <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" 
     [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i"">
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Great, this works for me. My question is about the appearance, how does it work what you have put?

Comment: You can find that in my snippet, this probably works but let me know if not.

Comment: Yes, the code works. What I said is that how does the [appearence] property work now?

Answer (score 0):

How about...?

```
<input matInput ... [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
     Name
   </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field 
           *ngIf="editIndex!=i" 
           floatLabel="never" 
           [appearance]="'none'" // Since you are not binding with any variable here, you can replace with appearance="none"
        >
           <input 
              matInput 
              placeholder="{{clients.name}}" // You can replace this with [placeholder]="clients.name"
              [(ngModel)]="clients.name" 
              [readonly]="editIndex !== i"
            />
        </mat-form-field>
   </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```